# Account Ledger Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-query-store

I have Write the below query for Account Ledger for Inventory POS with Accounts managment. Is this a good way to get account ledger of any account or there is some better way to get the account ledger.

Any Expert Suggestions Please.....??

Does this way will work fine when we use this query for getting ledger for all accounts balances at a same time.??

```
Select 'DV-'+Convert(Varchar,VoucherNo) As VoucherNo, DebitVouchersBody.AccountNo, AccountName, VoucherDate AS Date,     DebitVouchersBody.Narration, Debit, 0.00 As Credit 
From DebitVouchersBody 
Join ChartOfAccounts ON DebitVouchersBody.AccountNo=ChartOfAccounts.AccountNo 
Where DebitVouchersBody.AccountNo = '" & txtAccountId.Text & "' 
Union All  

Select 'CV-'+Convert(Varchar,VoucherNo) As VoucherNo, CreditVouchersBody.AccountNo, AccountName, VoucherDate AS Date, CreditVouchersBody.Narration, 0.00 As Debit, Credit 
From CreditVouchersBody
Join ChartOfAccounts ON CreditVouchersBody.AccountNo=ChartOfAccounts.AccountNo 
Where CreditVouchersBody.AccountNo = '" & txtAccountId.Text & "' 
Union All 

Select 'JV-'+Convert(Varchar,VoucherNo) As VoucherNo, JournalVouchersBody.AccountNo, AccountName, VoucherDate AS Date, JournalVouchersBody.Narration, Debit, Credit 
From JournalVouchersBody 
Join ChartOfAccounts ON JournalVouchersBody.AccountNo=ChartOfAccounts.AccountNo 
Where JournalVouchersBody.AccountNo = '" & txtAccountId.Text & "' 
Union All 

Select 'CD-'+Convert(Varchar,VoucherNo) As VoucherNo, BankDeposit.BankAccountNo, AccountName, VoucherDate AS Date, BankDeposit.Narration, Amount As Debit, 0.00 As Credit 
From BankDeposit Join ChartOfAccounts ON BankDeposit.BankAccountNo=ChartOfAccounts.AccountNo 
Where BankDeposit.BankAccountNo = '" & txtAccountId.Text & "' AND IsCheque='False' 
Union All  

Select 'BD-'+Convert(Varchar,VoucherNo) As VoucherNo, BankDeposit.BankAccountNo, AccountName, VoucherDate AS Date, BankDeposit.Narration, Amount As Debit, 0.00 As Credit 
From BankDeposit 
Join ChartOfAccounts ON BankDeposit.BankAccountNo=ChartOfAccounts.AccountNo 
Where BankDeposit.BankAccountNo = '" & txtAccountId.Text & "' AND IsCheque='True' 
Union All  

Select 'BD-'+Convert(Varchar,VoucherNo) As VoucherNo, BankDeposit.ReceivedFromAccountNo, AccountName, VoucherDate AS Date, BankDeposit.Narration, 0.00 As Debit, Amount As Credit 
From BankDeposit Join ChartOfAccounts ON BankDeposit.ReceivedFromAccountNo=ChartOfAccounts.AccountNo 
Where BankDeposit.ReceivedFromAccountNo = '" & txtAccountId.Text & "' AND IsCheque='True' 
Union All  

Select 'CT-'+Convert(Varchar,VoucherNo) As VoucherNo, BankCheques.BankAccountNo, AccountName, VoucherDate AS Date, BankCheques.Narration, Amount As Debit, 0.00 As Credit 
From BankCheques Join ChartOfAccounts ON BankCheques.BankAccountNo=ChartOfAccounts.AccountNo 
Where BankCheques.BankAccountNo = '" & txtAccountId.Text & "' AND IsOnline='False' 
Union All  

Select 'OT-'+Convert(Varchar,VoucherNo) As VoucherNo, BankCheques.AccountNoPayTo, AccountName, VoucherDate AS Date, BankCheques.Narration, 0.00 As Debit, Amount As Credit 
From BankCheques 
Join ChartOfAccounts ON BankCheques.AccountNoPayTo=ChartOfAccounts.AccountNo 
Where BankCheques.AccountNoPayTo = '" & txtAccountId.Text & "' AND IsOnline='True' 
Union All

Select 'SI-'+Convert(Varchar,Sales.SaleID) As VoucherNo, CustomerId As AccountNo, AccountName, Date, Sales.Narration, NetValue As Debit, PaidAmount As Credit 
From Sales 
Join ChartOfAccounts ON Sales.CustomerId=ChartOfAccounts.AccountNo 
Where CustomerId= '" & txtAccountId.Text & "' 
Union All  

Select 'SR-'+Convert(Varchar,SaleReturns.SaleReturnID) As VoucherNo, CustomerId As AccountNo, AccountName, Date, SaleReturns.Narration, PaidAmount As Debit, NetValue As Credit 
From SaleReturns 
Join ChartOfAccounts ON SaleReturns.CustomerId=ChartOfAccounts.AccountNo 
Where CustomerId= '" & txtAccountId.Text & "' 
Union All  

Select 'PI-'+Convert(Varchar,Purchases.PurchaseId) AS VoucherNo, VendorId As AccountNo, AccountName, Date, Purchases.Narration, AmountPaid AS Debit, NetValue AS Credit 
From Purchases 
Join ChartOfAccounts ON Purchases.VendorId=ChartOfAccounts.AccountNo 
Where VendorId= '" & txtAccountId.Text & "' 
Union All  

Select 'PR-'+Convert(Varchar,PurReturns.PurReturnId) AS VoucherNo, VendorId As AccountNo, AccountName, Date, PurReturns.Narration, NetValue AS Debit, AmountPaid AS Credit 
From PurReturns 
Join ChartOfAccounts ON PurReturns.VendorId=ChartOfAccounts.AccountNo 
Where VendorId= '" & txtAccountId.Text & "' 
Union All  

Select 'CC-'+Convert(Varchar,CExpiryClaims.ClaimID) As VoucherNo, CustomerId As AccountNo, AccountName, Date, NULL As Narration, 0.00 As Debit, TTLValue As Credit 
From CExpiryClaims 
Join ChartOfAccounts ON CExpiryClaims.CustomerId=ChartOfAccounts.AccountNo 
Where CustomerId= '" & txtAccountId.Text & "' 
Union All  

Select 'CR-'+Convert(Varchar,CExpiryReplies.ReplyID) As VoucherNo, CustomerId As AccountNo, AccountName, CexpiryReplies.Date, NULL As Narration, (IsNull(CexpiryReplies.TTLValue,0))+(IsNull(RepliedAmount,0)) As Debit, 0.00 As Credit 
From CExpiryReplies 
Join CExpiryClaims On CExpiryClaims.ClaimID=CExpiryReplies.ReplyID 
Join ChartOfAccounts ON CExpiryClaims.CustomerId=ChartOfAccounts.AccountNo 
Where CustomerId= '" & txtAccountId.Text & "' 
Union All 

Select 'VC-'+Convert(Varchar,ExpiryClaims.ClaimID) As VoucherNo, VendorId As AccountNo, AccountName, Date, NULL As Narration, TTLValue As Debit, 0.00 As Credit 
From ExpiryClaims 
Join ChartOfAccounts ON ExpiryClaims.VendorId=ChartOfAccounts.AccountNo 
Where VendorId= '" & txtAccountId.Text & "' 
Union All  

Select 'CR-'+Convert(Varchar,ExpiryReplies.ReplyID) As VoucherNo, VendorId As AccountNo, AccountName, ExpiryReplies.Date, NULL As Narration, 0.00 As Debit, (IsNull(expiryReplies.TTLValue,0))+(IsNull(RepliedAmount,0)) As Credit 
From ExpiryReplies 
Join ExpiryClaims On ExpiryClaims.ClaimID=ExpiryReplies.ReplyID 
Join ChartOfAccounts ON ExpiryClaims.VendorId=ChartOfAccounts.AccountNo 
Where VendorId= '" & txtAccountId.Text & "' 
Union All 

Select 'RI-'+Convert(Varchar,RecoveryBodyInvoice.RecoveryID) As VoucherNo, CustomerId As AccountNo, AccountName, RecoveryDate, REcoveryBodyInvoice.Narration, 0.00 As Debit, Amount As Credit 
From RecoveryBodyInvoice 
Join Recovery ON RecoveryBodyInvoice.RecoveryID = Recovery.RecoveryID 
join sales ON RecoveryBodyInvoice.SaleID=sales.SaleId 
Join ChartOfAccounts ON Sales.CustomerId=ChartOfAccounts.AccountNo 
Where CustomerId= '" & txtAccountId.Text & "' 
Union All 

Select 'RR-'+Convert(Varchar,RecoveryBodyWOInvoice.RecoveryID) As VoucherNo, CustomerId As AccountNo, AccountName, RecoveryDate, REcoveryBodyWOInvoice.Narration, 0.00 As Debit, Amount As Credit 
From RecoveryBodyWOInvoice 
Join Recovery ON RecoveryBodyWOInvoice.RecoveryID = Recovery.RecoveryID 
Join ChartOfAccounts ON CustomerId=ChartOfAccounts.AccountNo 
Where CustomerId= '" & txtAccountId.Text & "' 
Union All 

Select Null AS VoucherNo, Null As AccountNo, NULL As Name,Null As Date,'Opening Balance' AS Narration, OpeningDebit AS Debit, OpeningCredit As Crdit 
From ChartOfAccounts 
Where AccountNo = '" & txtAccountId.Text & "' 
Order By VoucherDate, VoucherNo
```

Comment: You need to read about, understand and start using parameterized queries before bobby tables comes to visit. http://bobby-tables.com/

Answer (score 1):

"Good way" requires understanding how you determine "good" vs. "bad". And no one reading your question has intimate knowledge of your schema or your goal - something that is needed to evaluate the correctness of your query or the efficiency.

Your query is "bad" in that it is susceptible to sql injection - so go read about that before you get hacked.

You convert from numeric to varchar but omit the length - which is a bad practice.

Your query selects all activity since the beginning of time for a given account. Such a resultset is unlikely to be generally useful.

Your last select statement (opening balance) does not include any date (open since when? Yes, there probably is a real date!) nor any identifying attributes like account id, name, etc. That is not consistent with the others - let reports manage the display of data.

You combine two different pieces of information into voucherno. That is bad practice. If you think this is really useful, then you probably want to zero-fill the converted ID value so you can "line up" the values in an actual report.

Your parameter usage is inconsistent, which makes your logic more difficult to understand. As best as I can tell (tldr), you effectively always compare the parameter to chartofaccounts.accountno. So actually do that in your where clauses to highlight the strange relationships in your schema (where accountno is customerid, vendorid, etc).

And lastly - always give your tables **useful** aliases and reference all columns with the appropriate alias - so that the reader knows which table is the source of any particular column. And you should always reference tables with the appropriate schema name too.